# is it possible to set a button id to a numeric value from a database

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am getting products from a database and setting the id of each product to `'product'.$row['product_id'];`. When I'm trying to hide the button (using Jquery) after it has been clicked nothing happens, any help would be mostly appreciated.

Button:

```
<a class="product" id="<?php echo 'product'.$row['product_id'];?>">add</a>
```

JS:

```
$('.product').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#proudct_id'+id).hide();
)};
```

Comment: Your selector is `'#proudct_id'+id` but it looks like your ID is going to be `product1`, etc

Comment: _hide the button in Ajax after it has been clicked_ You can simply use `$(this).hide();  `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `$(this)` to get the clicked one:

```js
$('.product').click(function() {
  $(this).hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Simulate PHP echo -->
<a class="product" id="product1">add1</a>
<a class="product" id="product2">add2</a>
<a class="product" id="product3">add3</a>
```

Comment: thanks for your help it wont let me accept your answer yet